# On $p$-Sylows for $S_{2p}$ ... $S_{(p-1)p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

This is quite a general question. The case for the previous $S_p$ is trivial and it seems the case with $S_{p^2}$ is different. For all $2\le n\le p-1$, those $p$-Sylows will have $p^n$ order.

So to make that happen, my idea is generally, for each case, I use $n$ different cyclic's generator (like $n$ different $p$-cycles) to generate a new group, which should contain $p^n$ elements.

Am I right?

Comment: Sylow subgroups of symmetric groups are well understood and are direct products of iterated wreath products of cyclic groups of order $p$. For $S_{p^k}$ you get $C_p \wr C_p \wr \cdots k\hbox{ times } \cdots \wr C_p$.

Comment: ... Sorry, I don't understand the direct products of iterated wreath products... What is that? By the way, is there a way to produce $S_{p^k}$ with the semi-direct product?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You cannot possibly understand the Sylow subgroups of $S_n$ without knowing what a wreath product is.