# For a group $G$ of order $p^n$, $G\cong H$ for some $H\le\Bbb Z_p\wr\dots\wr\Bbb Z_p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups, wreath-product

This is **Exercise 5.3.2** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5CBbb%20Z_p%5Cwr%5Cdots%5Cwr%5CBbb%20Z_p%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asubgroup%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24p%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3AWreath%20&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+%5Bwreath-product%5D+iterated), it is new to MSE. The result is mentioned in the following posts though:

- [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1934661/104041) to [$p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{p^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1934635/104041)
- [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1376605/104041) to [On the number of Sylow subgroups in Symmetric Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1376586/104041)
- [On $p$-Sylows for $S_{2p}$ ... $S_{(p-1)p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430726/104041)
- [When is normalizer of wreath product the wreath product of normalizers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4001203/104041)

Here are some previous questions of mine about Wreath products:

- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary $K$, is the diagonal subgroup of the base group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079892/104041)
- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)=1$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary, infinite $K$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082857/104041)
- [Showing that the restricted wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085628/104041)
- [The Frattini subgroup of the standard Wreath product of two quasicyclic groups is the group itself.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4339992/104041)
- [There exist infinite solvable $p$-groups with trivial centre. (Use a hint.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4340747/104041)

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

On page 32 and 33 of the book,

> Let $H$ and $K$ be permutation groups on sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. [. . .]
>
> If $\gamma\in H$, $y\in Y$, and $\kappa\in K$, define
>
> $$\gamma(y):\begin{cases} (x,y) \mapsto (x\gamma, y) & \\ (x,y_1) \mapsto (x,y_1) & y_1\neq y,\end{cases}$$
> and
>
> $$\kappa^\ast: (x,y)\mapsto (x,y\kappa).$$
>
> [. . .] The functions $\gamma\mapsto \gamma(y)$, with $y$ fixed, and $\kappa\mapsto \kappa^\ast$ are monomorphisms from $H$ and $K$ to ${\rm Sym}(X\times Y)$: let their images be $H(y)$ and $K^\ast$, respectively. Then the *wreath product* of $H$ and $K$ is the permutation group on $X\times Y$ [. . .]
>
> $$H\wr K=\langle H(y), K^\ast\mid y\in Y\rangle.$$

---

On page 41 of the book,

> If $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, we can think of them as permutation groups on their underlying sets via the right regular representation and form their wreath product $W=H\wr K$: this is called the *standard wreath product*.

### The Question:

> A group of order $p^n$ is isomorphic with a subgroup of the standard wreath product $$\underbrace{\Bbb Z_p\wr\dots\wr\Bbb Z_p.}_{n\text{ factors}}$$

Here $p$ is prime.

### Thoughts:

Since semidirect products are associative and each wreath product can be viewed as a semidirect product, the lack of parentheses in question makes sense.

---

Fix a prime $p$.

---

My first idea was to use induction on $n$, since for the base case $n=1$, we have that the group in question is $\Bbb Z_p$.

I didn't get anywhere here though.

---

Perhaps we could modify a proof of Cayley's theorem to do the exercise. Its statement:

> Each group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group.

---

Another useful theorem might be Sylow's First Theorem:

> For every prime factor $p$ with multiplicity $n$ of the order of a finite group $G$, there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, of order $p^n$.

A *Sylow $p$-subgroup* of a group $G$ is subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$ for $k$ maximal such that $p^k\mid\lvert G\rvert$.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cayley's Theorem, we can embed $G$ into the symmetric group $S_{|G|} = S_{p^n}$. So by Sylow's Theorem, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $S_{p^n}$.

(I prefer $C_p$ to ${\mathbb Z}_p$ for a cyclic group of order  $p$.) It is a standard result that $P \cong C_p \wr C_p \wr \cdots \wr C_p$ (with $n$ wreath factors.) Let's write that as $C_p^{\wr^n}$.

That is not hard to prove by induction. Assuming that $S_{p^{n-1}}$ has Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q \cong C_p^{\wr^{n-1}}$, by partitioning the set $\{1,2,\ldots,p^n\}$ into $p$ sets of size $p^{n-1}$, we see that $S_{p^n}$ contains the permutation wreath product $Q \wr C_p \cong C_p^{\wr^n}$ and by computing its order you can check that it is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.